# Pulling the first record out of a bunch of Switch statements in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a long list of JSON data that I need to loop through and break up into different lists which I save for later. But I need to figure out a way to capture the first value in each of the lists I'm creating quickly.

I was thinking of a true false boolean and setting it to false after the first time the switch statement was called, and then pushing that value into a new array, but it seems un-elegant.

Anyhow I was looking for some suggestions on how to handle this.

Here's my job so far.

```
 function dump_locations($obj){

    $i91 = array();
    $i95 = array();
    $i84 = array();
    $rt2 = array();
    $rt8 = array();
    $rt9 = array();
    $i395 = array();
    $rt15 = array();
    $rt72 = array();
    $other = array();

foreach($obj as $camera){
    switch($camera->name){
        case (preg_match('/^I-95/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($i95,$camera);
        break;
        case (preg_match('/^I-84/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($i84,$camera);
        break;
        case (preg_match('/^I-91/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($i91,$camera);
        break;
        case (preg_match('/^I-395/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($i395,$camera);
        break;
        case (preg_match('/^CT-15/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($rt15,$camera);
        break;
        case (preg_match('/^RT 2/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($rt2,$camera);
        break;
        case (preg_match('/^RT 8/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($rt8,$camera);
        break;
        case (preg_match('/^RT 9/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($rt9,$camera);
        break;
        case (preg_match('/^RT 72/', $camera->name) ? true : false) :
            array_push($rt72,$camera);
        break;
        default:
            array_push($other,$camera);
    }
}

    save_file('i91_cameras.json',$i91);
    save_file('i95_cameras.json',$i95);
    save_file('i84_cameras.json',$i84);
    save_file('rt2_cameras.json',$rt2);
    save_file('rt8_cameras.json',$rt8);
    save_file('rt9_cameras.json',$rt9);
    save_file('i395_cameras.json',$i395);
    save_file('rt15_cameras.json',$rt15);
    save_file('rt72_cameras.json',$rt72);
    save_file('other_cameras.json',$other);
}
```

Comment: A switch is really the wrong tool for the job here afaics.

Comment: Okay, what would u suggest?

Comment: use a proper single regex to match whatever you want. That is if I understand want you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks painful, especially with the multiple arrays. Why not make the regex match a capture group, and something like `/^(RT 2|RT 8|RT 9| etc...)/`, then you can use that capture group as an array index, and reduce the ENTIRE switch to just a few lines:

```
$data = array();
foreach($obj as $camera){
   if (preg_match('/^(I-95|I-84|etc...|RT 72)/', $camera->name, $matches)) {
      $data[$matches[1]][] = $camera;
   } else {
      $data['default'][] = $camera;
}
```

Now you have one array, keyed by the camera model, instead of MANY arrays, each with a different name, for which you'd have to write special code to handle (bad idea), or use variable-variables (an even worse idea).